# FBSDK accesstoken translation in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am having difficulties with translating this piece of Objective-C code:

```
- (void)_accessTokenChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
FBSDKAccessToken *token = notification.userInfo[FBSDKAccessTokenChangeNewKey];

if (!token) {
[self _deselectRow];
} else {
SUProfileTableViewCell *cell = (SUProfileTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_currentIndexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
NSInteger slot = [self _userSlotFromIndexPath:_currentIndexPath];
SUCacheItem *item = [SUCache itemForSlot:slot] ?: [[SUCacheItem alloc] init];
if (![item.token isEqualToAccessToken:token]) {
item.token = token;
[SUCache saveItem:item slot:slot];
cell.userID = token.userID;
}
}
}
```

Into:

```
func accessTokenChanged(notification: NSNotification) -> Void {
    var token: AnyObject? = notification.userInfo![FBSDKAccessTokenChangeNewKey] as! FBSDKAccessToken

    if (token == nil) {
        self.deselectRow()
    } else {
        let cell = self.usersTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(currentIndexPath!) as! FBUserCell
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        var slot: Int = self.userSlotFromIndexPath(currentIndexPath!)
        var item: CacheItem = Cache.itemForSlot(slot)!

        if (item.token.isEqualToAccessToken(token) == false) {
            item.token = token
            Cache.saveItem(item, slot: slot)
            cell.userIDLabel = token?.userID
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting an error on the if statement where two tokens are being compared: Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments. I get the same error if I put an exclamation mark before "item" in the if statement, but then with '!' obviously.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to re-create your error. How do you grab currentIndexPath?

Comment: Current index is the selected cell, either 0 or 1. var currentIndexPath: NSIndexPath? = NSIndexPath()

Comment: Have you tried using '?' after token for optional unwrapping?